# Cant call local AWS lambda container with curl/httr2

Tags: r, curl, aws-lambda, wget

I have an AWS Lambda container that I want to be able to ping from the terminal or tools such as R's httr2.  I tested it with Postman and it works and gives the appropriate response/output, I can see log messages etc.  However when I try the corresponding curl command in the command line or try to reconstruct it in httr2 I get an error.

I'm using a command from the Postman cURL snippet which is similar to the one in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-test.html) (the result is the same with the AWS docs default test command):

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data '{
    ...
}'
```

which returns `curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed`

The common solution to this is to add `--http0.9` to the command, however I then get:

```
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
```

Fine, I add `--output -` and the terminal shows:

```
?:000
User-Agent: curl/7.86.0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: txt/json
Content-Length: 402

{
    ...
```

and nothing happens...

The equivalent wget from postman code snippets works fine (logs show up, output is written etc.):

```
wget --no-check-certificate --quiet \
  --method GET \
  --timeout=0 \
  --header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
  --body-data '{
    ...
}' \
   'http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations'
```

R's httr2:

```r
library(httr2)

url <- "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations"

req <- request(url)

headers = c(
  'Content-Type' = 'text/plain'
)

body = list(
    # stuff
)

req <- req |>
    req_headers(
        'Content-Type' = 'text/plain'
    )  |>
    req_body_json(body)

result <- req |> req_method("GET") |> req_perform()
```